# How to build x64 and x86 projects that reference same projects

Tags: c#, compilation, x86-64

I have three projects, **ProjectA (exe)**, **ProjectB (exe)** and **ProjectD (class library)**

Project A references the System.Data.OracleClient.dll and ProjectD. Project B just references ProjectD. The 32-bit client version of oracle is installed and therefore ProjectA has to be a 32-bit application. Project B can be built as a 64-bit application.

**Project A build settings:**

Platform: Active (x86)

Platform target: x86

**Project B build settings:**

Platform: Active (Any CPU)

Platform target: Any CPU

My questions are what should the build settings be for ProjectD (the class library) and when ProjectA and ProjectB get built does it build ProjectD differently? A deeper explanation of the CLR would be great in terms of communications of the projects.

ProjectA and ProjectB are to be used on 64-bit Windows Server 2008. No installation, just standalone exe's.

Comment: "oracle client dll is a 32-bit dll" why do you think so?

Comment: Sorry, I should rephrase that. The 32-bit client is installed on the server (can't be changed) hence why it uses the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the Platform target setting for the EXE project matters.  That's the assembly that gets loaded first and determines the bitness of the entire process.

A DLL doesn't get a choice, it *must* be compatible with whatever was selected by the EXE project.  Picking AnyCPU for a DLL project is therefore almost always the correct selection.

There are just a few cases where you'd use an explicit setting.  You'd only do so if you know that the class library has a dependency on some kind of native code, like the Oracle provider, **and** that trying to run that native code in the wrong bitness produces a completely inscrutable exception.  You can avoid that exception and get a (slightly) better one by picking the Platform target for the DLL, the program will fail with a BadImageFormatException early when it tries to load the assembly.  Albeit that this exception isn't exactly a very informative one either.  Some odds that an admin is going to try to reinstall the DLL a couple of times before deciding that the real problem is elsewhere.

So basic ground rules: pick x86 for the EXE project, AnyCPU for all other class library projects, a nastygram to Oracle for doing nothing to make this easy.

Comment: After DLL Hell, I faced this issue and did't know that it will be solved much fast as slow as previous. Thanks for defining the chaining of 'Any CPU' and explicit platform.

Answer (score 3):

> My questions are what should the build settings be for ProjectD (the
>   class library) and when ProjectA and ProjectB get built does it build
>   ProjectD differently? A deeper explanation of the CLR would be great
>   in terms of communications of the projects.

Just use `Any CPU` for your lib. It'll build a unique assembly that can be executed in both 32-bit en 64-bit environments.

Technically, the *just in time compilation* with either produce 32-bit code or 64-bit code at runtime.