# Compile child process and copy binaries

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Currently I have a project A (64 bit) that references projects B, C, and D (all 32 bit). And I set `Copy Local = True`, such that all projects are compiled and the binaries are copied to the `bin` folder of project A. The binaries `B.exe`, `C.exe` and `D.exe` all run as a child process of `A.exe`. However Visual Studio complains with:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "AMD64" and the processor architecture of the reference 'project B' "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Should I just ignore the warning? Or should I just post build events to build and copy the other projects? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

> Compile child process and copy binaries

AFAIK, I am afraid you can not ignore this warning. This mismatch may cause run-time failures. Just like Mario said [on this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/644c2f9c-f06a-496a-b497-6420a7919fdb/64-bit-app-calling-32-bit-dll?forum=csharpgeneral):

> A 64bit executable cannot call a 32bit dll and viceversa. Unless you
> actually need your application to be 64bit, the simplest option is to
> set it to target x86. This will still allow it to run on both 32 and
> 64bit versions of Windows.

To resolve this warning, you could select x86 for the EXE project A or you just use post build events to build and copy the other projects. Check [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499553/how-to-build-x64-and-x86-projects-that-reference-same-projects) for details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are referring to an article talking about DLLs, I am not talking about DLLs. I am talking about actual child processes, launched by `new Process{....}.Start()`. And I cannot select x86 for project A, because it uses like 50 GB of memory.