# How do I import my user control dll to my new project?

Tags: c#

I have a user control project which contains a few controls I made myself. This project's output type is Class Library which produces a .dll file so I can import that in other projects. My problem here is when I rebuild the .dll project with Any CPU and import that dll to my second project I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in SecondProject.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'TestUserControlsDLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890abcdef' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

When I rebuild my dll project in 64bit I can see the user controls in design view but then I can't run my second project by clicking F5. This question is probably asked before but I'm at the point which I don't even know how to search about this problem.

What I try to do is import my dll output (user control project) into another project (which will be 64 bit) and be able to see the controls in design view and also able to run my project.

Problem solved..

I don't know how but creating a new dll project and just copy-paste my controls inside that new project under new namespace solved all of my problems. It's working now

Comment: AnyCPU [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500181/11683). Do you also have "Prefer 32-bit"?

Comment: If I read the answer in link correctly is suggest to my exe be 32 bit I have to use x64

Comment: No, it just suggests picking AnyCPU for the library.

Comment: I tried it but it did not worked for me. I rebuild my library project in AnyCPU and my second as x64. I'm able to see my controls in design view but I get the same error when I run my application.

Answer (score -1):

take a look, at both target framework versions. (Project properties)
e.g. if your exe is 4.6.1 and your dll is 4.7.2, you get this error

Comment: I rebuild them both in same version but I still get the error